# Deploy and download a wordpress application to google compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

How to deploy a local wordpress instance to **google compute engine** and download the same. I manage to deploy to google app engine, looking around for the document to deploy to google compute engine and download the same. With the existing post I can see its defn possible, but not able to locate the right document.

Also is it possible to deploy using `gcloud` commands ?, what is the command to use ?

I tried this command **`gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml`** but it keep complaining [application] is not used by gcloud. When I remove this tag, it keeps complaning endlessly. Is there a different app.yaml structure for **compute engine** and **app engine**.

How can I generate app.yaml file that is compatible with **compute engine** ?. Can it be downloaded some where or using a gcloud command ?, **`gcloud config`** doesnt seem to generate one.

Answer (score 0):

We *just* finished working on a tool and guide to help do exactly what you're asking:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/wordpress

Let us know if you run into any issues!

Comment: Thanks the url doesn't seem to load. Can you please check.

Comment: would like to know your thought on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497057/wordpress-google-app-engine-compatibility

Comment: Sorry, they changed the path on me:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/wordpress