# wordpress google app engine compatibility

Tags: google-app-engine, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, genesis

I have been trying to host a wordpress site in gae. Have been facing issue, even established plugin seem to break. I created this ticket seeking experts input and advice. I am java developer and have no idea about wordpress, php and google cloud. so your input's are appreciated.

With google cloud's, gae env. The plugin are deployed to the local wordpress env running in google cloud container. Then using google cloud command line tool to google app engine  and activated. A plugin can not directly be deployed to gae wordpress env as the wp-content folder is read only.

Is this feasible?, most of the plugin seem to break even the established like (genesis). I came across the following error.

**`The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.`**

**`Fatal error: Class 'EE_DMS_Core_4_1_0' not found`**

**`Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/10. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`** -- when creating page with a plugin

A member from a google team asked to extract the file directly to  `wordpress/wp-content/plugins` or `wordpress/wp-content/themes`. I tried and that don't seem to work either, wordpress is not picking those plugin. The plugin I tried are Genesis framework and child theme, event espresso.

I doubt if wordpress can oblige to google cloud way of doing things. Please clarify.

GAE Ref : https://wp.gaeflex.ninja/2016/04/07/running-wordpress-on-app-engine-standard-environment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not allowed to write to local file system on Google App Engine standard environment. Maybe you should choose App Engine flexible environment because App Engine flexible environment allows you to write to local file system.

That said, by default it enforces strict permission for security reasons. Your options are 1) Use your own Dockerfile and change the permission of `wordpress/wp-content/uploads` directory. or 2) somehow use `/upload` for the uploads folder.

Also, App Engine is multi server architecture. By default, App Engine will spin up new instances when your blog gets lots of traffic. You may need to think about whether or not the plugin works well in such environment. Because the local files are not shared among multiple instances.

Comment: You may want to check if the plugin has an option to use cloud storage (instead of local file system) for the upload files.

Comment: Thanks that helped, to correct my original question. Genesis framework does work in gae, it's the child theme for genesis breaks in gae eventhough it works fine in local env. Also eventespresso doesn't seem to work in gae, I wrote to eventespresso support regarding this. Yet to have their response.